# Object does not name a type - C++

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I'm trying to implement a *Set* based on  a *Binary Tree Search*. So i'm building this set starting from a **root** (pointer to Node), where Node has a value, right and left child (both pointers to Node also). So this way i could set a new node on the right of the root node by pointing root->right to the created node and so on. Take a look at the definitions:

```
template <class T>
class Set
{
    public:
        Set();
        ~Set();
        void push(const T&);
        bool belongs(const T&) const;
        void remove(const T&);
        const T& min() const;
        const T& max() const;
        unsigned int cardinal() const;
        void show(std::ostream&) const;

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Set<T> &c) {
            c.show(os);
            return os;
        }

    private:

        struct Node
        {
            Node(const T& v);
            T value;
            Node* left;
            Node* right; 
        };

        Node* root_;
        int cardinal_;

    Node & fatherOfNode(const Node & root, const T & key, const bool hook) const;

};

...

// This function is the one with errors.
template <class T>
Node & Set<T>::fatherOfNode(const Node & root, const T & key, const bool hook) const {
    // Some code
}
```

So i'm having this error:

```
/home/jscherman/ClionProjects/algo2-t3-bts/set.hpp:247:1: error: ‘Node’ does not name a type
 Node & Set<T>::fatherOfNode(const Node & root, const T & key, const bool hook) const {
 ^
```

I've seen a lot of posts related with this error, but most of them were caused by writing functions implementations before its definitions. As you can see, the implementation of **fatherOfNode** is below its definition, so it doesn't seem to be my case.

Any idea about what is going on?

Comment: It should be `Set<T>::Node`.

Comment: What is it wrong with the question? I think that i've been specific and clear enough. Could you tell me what did i do wrong so i won't repeat it in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Node` is an internal class in `Set`, so outside of this class you need to resolve this with:

```
Set<T>::Node
```

So your function definition will need to be:

```
template <class T>
typename Set<T>::Node & Set<T>::fatherOfNode(const Set<T>::Node & root, const T & key, const bool hook) const {
```

[Here it is, working.](http://ideone.com/HpuYca)